# How to force logback to flush logs from a single logger tied to AsyncAppender

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

In SpringBoot, I am using Logback's AsyncAppender to output logs asynchronously.
I would like to know how to force a flush from a single logger that tied to AsyncAppender.
I know that I can flush all the loggers with the following code.

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.stop();
```

For a single logger, is there any way to flush the log queued by AsyncAppender like `LoggerFactory.getLogger().flush`?